# How to detect certificate issues on the user browser

Tags: javascript, security, https, web, ssl-certificate

As we are using more and more tools from 3rd party suppliers on our https only website we are being surprised several times by changes made by our suppliers that break the security of the site witch can even result on a not wanted browser message to the user.

The more classic errors are forced calls to http: contents, this are blocked and can brake the usability of the site they do not result on a message to the user.

Other classical error is a non valid certificate, that can happen because the certificate is no longer valid or because it was issued by a non recognized CA on the user browser.

This last errors are the ones that we are trying to identify a way to get warned every time a user gets an error like this so we can act asap.

Can anyone show me a way or if at least is feasible.

Thanks,

Comment: I believe it's not feasible but I suggest you to read this example. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/How_to_check_the_secruity_state_of_an_XMLHTTPRequest_over_SSL it may help..

Answer (score 0):

Non valid certificate check will be fired before browser will download any javascript from site.
This mean if it works - certificate fine or user already trust it.

If You try to check third party site You can try add 1 pixel image on page and wait for onLoad onError events.